# How to get CONNECT request headers when receiving GET/POST request?

Tags: node.js, https

```
    const httpsServer = createServer();

    httpsServer.on('request', (req, res) => {
        // how to get the connect headers ?
    });

    httpsServer.on('connect', (req, clientSocket, head) => {
        const connectHeaders = req.headers;

        const mitmClientSocket = net.connect({
            port: 9999, 
            host: '127.0.0.1', 
            // timeout: 15000
        }, () => {
            if (!mitmClientSocket.destroyed && !clientSocket.destroyed) {
                if (!clientSocket.writableEnded) {
                    clientSocket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
                                        'Proxy-agent: MITM-proxy\r\n' +
                                        '\r\n');
                }
                if (!mitmClientSocket.writableEnded) {
                    mitmClientSocket.write(head);
                }
                mitmClientSocket.pipe(clientSocket);
                clientSocket.pipe(mitmClientSocket);
            }
        });
    });
    
    httpsServer.listen(9999, () => {
        const address = httpsServer.address();
    });
```

Hi guys, I'm implementing an MITM in Nodejs language but struggling with how to get the CONNECT request headers when receiving the GET/POST request. I found a ugly way to use mitmClientSocket.localPort and req.socket.remotePort to link CONNECT and GET/POST. Do you have any better thougts?

Thank you in advance.

how to get the CONNECT request headers when receiving the GET/POST request